# A natural map of higher direct images.

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $f\colon X \rightarrow Y$ be a proper morphism of schemes, $Y$ noetherian (I don't know which of those assumptions is actually needed for the claim).

According to my lecture notes, for $\mathcal{O}_X$-modules $\mathcal{F}, \mathcal{G}$ there exists a canonical map of higher direct images

$R^qf_{\ast}\mathcal{F} \otimes R^pf_{\ast} \mathcal{G} \rightarrow R^{p+q} f_{\ast}(\mathcal{F} \otimes \mathcal{G})$

How is this map defined/does it arise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want a fancy, or a non-fancy answer?

If you want a non-fancy answer it suffices to construct a map of presheaves

$$A^pf_\ast\mathcal{F}\otimes A^qf_\ast\mathcal{G}\to A^{p+q}f_\ast(\mathcal{F}\otimes\mathcal{G})$$

where $A^i f_\ast\mathcal{M}$ (the notation of which I just made up, it's not standard), for a quasicoherent module $\mathcal{M}$, is the one sending $U\to H^i(f^{-1}(U),\mathcal{M})$. So now, it's clear want to do. You have a bilinear map

$$H^p(f^{-1}(U),\mathcal{F})\times H^q(f^{-1}(U),\mathcal{G})\to H^{p+q}(f^{-1}(U),\mathcal{F}\otimes\mathcal{G})$$
coming from the functoriality of cohomology. Alternatively, if you assume that your schemes separated and quasicompact, it's clear how to construct the map on Cech cycles, with affine open covers.

This map then gives a map of presheaves

$$A^pf_\ast\mathcal{F}\otimes A^qf_\ast\mathcal{G}\to A^{p+q}f_\ast(\mathcal{F}\otimes\mathcal{G})\to R^{p+q}f_\ast(\mathcal{F}\otimes\mathcal{G})$$

where the last map is the canonical map associated to a sheafification. Then, by the universal property of sheafification, we obtain a map

$$R^p f_\ast\mathcal{F}\otimes R^qf_\ast\mathcal{G}\to R^{p+q}f_\ast(\mathcal{F}\otimes\mathcal{G})$$

as desired.

There may be a fancier way not needing to pass through the presheaf.

Comment: This might be a really stupid question, but I actually wanted to do it like that. But I couldn't figure out how the bilinear map "coming from functoriality of cohomology" is defined. How does this work? I would like to just take injective resolutions and see everything works out, but how do I get an injective resolution of $\mathcal{F} \otimes \mathcal{G}$ from ones of $\mathcal{F}$ and $\mathcal{G}$? Or maybe this is not the right way to see it?

Comment: @Louis That's a good question. You can always reduce to defining this map on quasicompact $U$, so $f^{-1}(U)$ is also quasicompact, in which case you can compute derived cohomology with Cech cohomology. Is it clear how to define the map in this context, just defining it for each open affine covering? I'll have to think if there is a nice way of getting this purely in terms of derived cohomology. Sorry for not having a quick answer!

Comment: In Cech cohomology, I would just map the $\mathcal{F}(U_{i_0,...,i_q}) \otimes \mathcal{G}(U_{j_0,..., j_p})$ to the $\mathcal{F} \otimes \mathcal{G}(U_{i_0,...,i_q,j_0,...,j_p})$ if $i_k, j_l$ distinct, I guess? But in the assumptions given above, a lot of things needed for Cech cohomology are missing, $X$ is not separated and the modules are not even asked to be quasi-coherent. Also, don't worry about not being able to answere fast. A lot of  thanks already anyways!

Comment: @Louis While being not separated/qc and not having a quasicoherent module means that you don't have canonical Leray covers, for any paracompact (so, in particular, quasicompact) space, derived cohomology agrees with Cech (see 4) of the first answer here http://mathoverflow.net/questions/4214/equivalence-of-grothendieck-style-versus-cech-style-sheaf-cohomology). Thus, you can compute $H^i(f^{-1}(U),\mathcal{M})$ in the sense of Cech (although it's the direct limit!) and it suffices to take the cofinal system of affines. This works, but seems more involved than I'd hope for this question.

Comment: Thanks for the link, I didn't know that! However, as you already mentioned, it would be nice if there was a'solution' not using Cech cohomology.